# Regex to parse string using delimiters to match pattern with possible NULL values

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, pattern-matching

I am trying to frame a regular expression to use it in SQL to parse a string based on delimiters.
Lets say, My string is as follows:
ABC;EFG;;123

The above string has 5 data elements delimited by semi colon.
Please note the 3rd value is missing or blank.

I tried a regex as [^;]+ to match a string of characters except semicolon.
But this is not matching the missing 3rd value.

**Actual output - What i am getting now:**
    1st element = ABC
    2nd element = EFG
    3rd element = 123
    4th element = NULL

**Expected output - Which i need:**
    1st element = ABC
    2nd element = EFG
    3rd element =  or NULL
    4th element = 123

Can you please help me understanding how to match these type of missing values in between patterns?

Comment: Actually, that is why it is sometimes best to just use a CSV parser or split with a character. Check [`[^;]+|(?<=;|^)(?=;|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/E3zXjq/1).

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew. With your code suggestion ` [^;]+|(?<=;|^)(?=;|$)`, I am getting first 3 values correctly but not getting the 4th value. The output that i am getting now is **ABC, EFG, <blank>, <blank>**... The 4th element should be **'123'**. Any other suggestion? Appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Why? The 4th group has `123` in it. Look at the demo again. Where are you trying this regex?

Comment: I debugged the pattern in regex debugger [link](https://regex101.com/r/E3zXjq/1/debugger). there it shows successful match for first 3 values but match failed for 4th time. I tried the pattern in sql regex also.

Comment: I saw the demo and it is showing the match correctly there. Not sure it is behaving differently with SQL regex. When i use regexp_extract('ABC;EFG;;123', '[^;]+|(?<=;|^)(?=;|$)', 1, 4), I should get the value '123' since thats the 4th match. But i getting blank and instead I am getting '123' only during the 5th match.

Comment: See MATCH INFORMATION pane. You are looking at the wrong place in regex101 for the matches. In SQL this regex won't work. Is it Oracle? Anyway, it won't work in any SQL. Look for a solution other than regex.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your help!